# Delete rows in vector VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, conditional-statements, delete-row

I'm trying to delete rows in a vector depending on the value of another vector in a VBA function that will return a vector. Thanks.

For example:

Conditions = [1; 0; 1; 1; 0] (5x1)

Data = [0.6; 0.7; 0.75; 0.81; 0.94] (5x1)

Expected Result = [0.6; 0.75; 0.81] (3x1)

```
Function RANGEIF(data As Range, condition As Range) As Range
'
' Inputs
'
' data:         Vector Nx1 of data
' condition:    Vector Nx1 of binairy conditions
'
' Outputs
'
' RANGEIF:      Vector Nx1 of specific data

' Variable declaration
Dim nRowData As Integer
Dim nRowCond As Integer

' Input vector size
nRowData = data.Rows.Count
nRowCond = condition.Rows.Count

' Input validation
If nRowData <> nRowCond Then
    msg = "Error: Input vector sizes do not match"
    MsgBox msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    GoTo endnow
End If

' Conditional range
For j = nRowCond To 1 Step -1
    If condition(j, 1).Value <> 1 Then
        data.Cells(j, 1).Delete
    End If
Next j

Set RANGEIF = data

endnow:

End Function
```

Comment: Are you running this from a worksheet cell as a UDF, or from another VBA  procedure?  A UDF cannot delete cells on a worksheet.  Also, you declare nRowData and nRowCond but then don't set the value of either of them...

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to include code for the vector sizes (nRowData and nRowCond). It's now corrected.

Comment: As for the function, yes I'm running this from a worksheet. I want to use both vectors to create a new vector,RANGEIF. I will then use RANGEIF in a function. 

For example: AVERAGE ( RANGEIF ( A1:A5 , B1:B5 ) )

Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as not all values are filtered out...

```
Function RANGEIF(data As Range, condition As Range)
    Dim n As Long, rv() As Variant, i As Long, msg, j As Long

    ' Input validation
    If data.Rows.Count <> condition.Rows.Count Then
        msg = "Error: Input vector sizes do not match"
        MsgBox msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        Exit Function
    End If

    n = Application.CountIf(condition, 1)
    If n > 1 Then
        ReDim rv(1 To n, 1 To 1)
        i = 1
        For j = 1 To data.Rows.Count
            If condition(j, 1).Value = 1 Then
                rv(i, 1) = data(j, 1)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next j
        RANGEIF = rv
    Else
        'what to do if no values are available?
        RANGEIF = "No values"
    End If

End Function
```